# Is $(p^{\frac{p^2+1}{p^5-1}}-x^{p^3})^{p^2}+p^{p^2+1}x-p^{p^2+\frac{p^2+1}{p^5-1}} $ eisenstein?

Tags: number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I could not decide whether the following polynomial is $$f(x)=(p^{\frac{p^2+1}{p^5-1}}-x^{p^3})^{p^2}+p^{p^2+1}x-p^{p^2+\frac{p^2+1}{p^5-1}}$$  an eisenstein  polynomial?

If I write simply
\begin{align}
f(x)&=(p^{\frac{p^2+1}{p^5-1}}-x^{p^3})^{p^2}+p^{p^2+1}x-p^{p^2+\frac{p^2+1}{p^5-1}} \\ 
&=x^{p^{5}}-\binom{p^2}{p^2-1}p^{\frac{p^2+1}{p^5-1}}x^{p^3(p^2-1)}+\cdots+p^{p^2+1}x+p^{p^2 \cdot \frac{p^2+1}{p^5-1}}-p^{p^2+\frac{p^2+1}{p^5-1}}
\end{align}
To show $f(x)$ is Eisenstein, we need to show $p^2$ does not divide the constant term $\left( p^{p^2 \cdot \frac{p^2+1}{p^5-1}}-p^{p^2+\frac{p^2+1}{p^5-1}} \right)$. Clearly $p^2$ divides $p^{p^2+\frac{p^2+1}{p^5-1}}$.

So $ p^2$ must not divide $p^{p^2 \cdot \frac{p^2+1}{p^5-1}}=p^{\frac{p^4}{p^5-1}}\cdot p^{\frac{p^2}{p^5-1}}$.

I think this is true.

any comments please

**Edit:** As mentioned by @reuns, the polynomial $f(x)$ is not Eisenstein over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ but over some extension

Comment: Your polynomial is not in $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$.

Comment: @reuns, I mean $\mathbb{Z}_p$, the ring of $p$-adic integers

Comment: what does the symbol $x^\alpha$ mean when $x$ is a $p$-adic number and $\alpha$ is a rational number?

Comment: @hunter, if $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, then there is a unit $u$ and a positive exponent $n$ such that $x=p^nu$. Therefore $x^a=p^{na}u^a$ implies $v(x^a)=na>0$ implies $x^a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. For $x \in \mathbb{Q}_p \setminus \mathbb{Z}_p$, i think we have to use interpolation.

Comment: Any suggestion to improve the question is welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your polynomial is not in $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$.

To help your understanding:
$x^2-2^{1/2}$ is not in $\Bbb{Q}_2[x]$, it is in $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt2)[x]$ and in $K[x]$ for any field extension of $\Bbb{Q}_2$ containing $2^{1/2}$.

It is Eisenstein as a polynomial of $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt2)[x]$ but not as a polynomial of $ \Bbb{Q}_2(2^{1/4})[x]$

Comment: Can I say the polynomial $f(x)$ is Eisenstein over $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p^5-1})$ ?

Comment: No, there is no $\sqrt{p^5-1}$ appearing anywhere. You certainly don't have much reason to look at this particular polynomial, if you obtained it from a calculation then you made a mistake somewhere. And does it look Eisenstein? What is the valuation of the constant term? (the valuation normalized such that $v(p^{1/(p^5-1)})=1$)

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I got this polynomial without any mistake. I understand the polynomial is not Eisenstein over $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Suppose we extend the field to $\mathbb{Q}_p\left( p^{\frac{p^2+1}{p^5-1}}\right)$. Does it help the polynomial $f(x)$ to be Eisenstein over the extended ring $\mathbb{Z}_p\left[p^{\frac{p^2+1}{p^5-1}} \right]$ ?

Comment: $O_K$ is larger than $\mathbb{Z}_p\left[p^{\frac{p^2+1}{p^5-1}} \right]$ when $K=\mathbb{Q}_p\left( p^{\frac{p^2+1}{p^5-1}}\right)$

Comment: Thanks. I missed the size of the integer ring. Anyway, what is the main obstruction becoming $f(x)$ an Eisenstein over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ ? I think the obstruction is that the coefficient involving $p^{\frac{p^2+1}{p^5-1}}$ doesn't belong to $\mathbb{Z}_p$. So if we consider $f(x)$ instead on the ring $O_K$, it would be Eisenstein. Am I right ?